# Can I deduplicate records to save memory?

Tags: java, record

I have lots of java records that store the equality value. May I deduplicate them to save memory? My records is fully immutable.
Because I read and construct them from a stream style data source(A JSON stream or csv stream), so I think they will be distinct object in memory. But most of them contains the same value.

Such as use a HashMap? I see the JVM internal string pool, but it's only for String and they're lived too long.

Comment: There are many ways to trade cpu usage and code complexity for memory depending on the characteristics of the data. First see whether you truly need to keep the objects in memory, or whether you can stream them. Using a HashMap to deduplicate is very simple straight and forward, and definitely worth a try. An open addressing implementation can save a further ~48 bytes per unique item. Storing fields in arrays instead of objects is annoying but can save another ~16 bytes. Be aware of compressed OOPs and object alignment. Stop when it gets cheaper to buy more RAM than to complicate the codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep the count for each record, you can use `Map<MyRecord, Integer>`:

```
List<MyRecord> list = ...;
Map<MyRecord, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (MyRecord myRecord : list) {
  map.compute(myRecord, (key, value) -> value == null ? 1 : value + 1);
}
```

This approach uses [Map.compute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to calculate the values.

If you only need to get rid any duplicates, adding to a `Set<MyRecord>` is enough:

```
List<MyRecord> list = ...;
Set<MyRecord> set = new HashSet<>(list);
```